# Is it safe to compile againts later JDK?

Tags: java

I have some big projects running on Java 6. But I plan to start building them in Java 8 since a lot of build tools have moved away from Java 6.

Is it safe for me to simply compile them with Java 8 and then deploy them in a web container running Java 8? If not, what are the considerations?

FYI, they don't have a proper automated test suite in place.

Comment: This is quite difficult to say without knowing the code base. Why don't you just try it in a development environment and see what happens? Unfortunately you don't have automated tests, so you'll have to fall back to manual testing.

Comment: That means, there's a chance that the code will break? I notice that Oracle has provided some compatibility issues on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198 I guess yes, it might break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems can be related to:

- [deprecated methods](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A1000033) that are removed in java 8 and you used in the old java 6 code
- [different behaviour](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999154) for some methods:

> There are aspects of the platform's behavior that are intentionally unspecified and the underlying implementation may change in a platform release.

- configuration of web container that can be different from a version supporting java 6 and the version supporting java 8
- external libraries that changed during the passage from java 6 to java 8 removing old methods so that your code can't compile

So yes it is possible that the passage from java 6 to java 8 can broke your code.

But if the code compile it is quite sure that the behaviour of the code is the same, because **generally** (but not always) a retro compatibility is granted. You can be sure of that only running a complete set of unit tests both on java 6 and java 8 versions.

---

Here some example of not compatibility between java 6 and java 7:

[JDK-6527962](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6527962) : **Retire the non-standard package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.** If your code use this package the it doesn't compile on java 8

[JDK-6563734](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6563734) : **Path2D.Float and Path2D.Double should have final getPathIterator methods** If your code ovewrite the methods declared final the code will not compile passing to java 8

Here a complete official list of [incompatibilities between java 6 and java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities)

Here a complete official list of [incompatibilities between java 7 and java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198)

Comment: Do you actually have examples of methods removed in Java 8, as far as I know the first removal of deprecated methods might happen in Java 9, but iirc it has never happened in earlier versions (besides non-public API stuff)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't if a method was removed, but surely there are methods that changed signature throwing exceptions or changing them to final so that extension of them result in not compilable code

Comment: In my experience that doesn't happen (or at least: I can't recall any example of it), Java is usually pretty strict in retaining backwards compatibility. There have been some problems in the past with changes in behavior, or people abusing 'bugs' that were later fixed breaking their software.

Comment: The non standard package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg for example has been removed http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6527962

Comment: Sure, but that is outside the public API of Java, most things in `com.sun` and similar packages are Sun/Oracle JVM specific and can change or be removed at any time.

Comment: That was only an example, I added other example in the answer and a link to list of incompatibilites between java 6 and 7 and between java 7 and 8

Answer (score 2):

It usually should be, since most of the features are backward compatible. However, there are no guarantees. Please do follow the proper process and do testing before rolling out to production.

For web container , with jdk, version would also have changed. This may cause some problems depending upon the software vendor and what all services you are using from the container ( JNDI, connection pooling etc).I once had a problem in migrating application to higher version of JDK. We also upgraded Websphere.  We were using JSF, and higher version of WAS had JSF jars included, which was clashing with our application jars.

Your apps may be using a lot of 3rd party library which may be impacted. Again, mostly you should be Ok, but there can be small issues. Without knowing your applications, I can only suggest migrate and test to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test things very thoroughly. If there are bugs, then it is imperative to find them and fix them before you move on to the next version. If you have a sunny day scenario and do not have bugs coming from the upgrade, then at least you know that for sure after the testing.

However, you need to know what to focus on. You need to read about changes applied on [version 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) and on [version 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/).